# Fat arrow function and nest's decorator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to use fat arrow function with a nestjs decorator in a controller.

So is it possible to do something like this :

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  findAll = (): string  => 'This is coming from a fat arrow !';
}
```

With this code typescript is telling me this : `Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression` so it isn't working.

I prefer to use fat arrow function instead of this "traditional" function :

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string {
    return 'This is not comming from a fat arrow';
  }
}
```

This is why I am asking if something like this a possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the answer is no, for the very reason of how the `arrow function` differs from a `function` in JavaScript, namely changing the lexical `this` and `arguments`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/9576186) goes into a lot of detail about how `function () {}` differs from `myFunction = () => {}`.

Along with that, using arrow functions would disallow a lot of using class functions, so if you are injecting any instances of a service, you would not be able to use them.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppController {
  constructor (private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('/')
  hello(): string {
    return this.appService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

Would work and return the string from the `appService.sayHello()` function, but this

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppController {
  constructor (private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('/')
  hello = (): string => {
    return this.appService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

would not return the string from the `appService.sayHello()` function because it does not know about the `appService`.

Comment: Alright, this seems more clear to me. Thank you for this complete answer.